# Python BeautifulSoup: 'list_iterator' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the text inside  from the following html structure:

```
<div class="account-age">
    <label></label>
    <div>
        <div>
             <span>Text to extract</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the following Beautiful Soup code to do it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(html, "lxml")
div = soup.find("div", {"class": "account-age"})
span = div.children[1].children[0].children[0]
text = span.get_text()
```

Unfortunately, Beautiful Soup is throwing the error: 'list_iterator' object is not subscriptable. How can I fix this to extract the text I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do this by directly chaining the tags from the root `div`:

```
div.div.div.span.get_text()
# u'Text to extract'
```

Answer (score 1):

The property `children` is an generator. As the error says, it is not subscriptable. To get a list, use `contents` instead:

```
div.contents[1].contents[0].contents[0]
```

See [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children).

Answer (score 0):

First locate the `div`, and then access the `span` text using an attribute as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = """<div class="account-age">
    <label></label>
    <div>
        <div>
             <span>Text to extract</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>"""

soup = bs(html, "lxml")
div = soup.find('div', class_='account-age')
print(div.span.text)
```

This would display:

```
Text to extract
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
html ='''<div class="account-age">
    <label></label>
    <div>
        <div>
             <span>Text to extract</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>'''
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find("div", {"class": "account-age"})
span = div.find('span')
text = span.get_text()
print(text)
```

Result:

```
Text to extract
```